# Copying data from one array to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays as given below.

```
var obj1 = [
        {
            "POST": "Developer",
            "USERNAME": [
                "User1",
                "User2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "POST": "Tester",
            "USERNAME": [
                "User3"
            ]
        }
    ]

var obj2 = [
        {
            "USERNAME": "User1",
            "USER_PASSWORD": "test1"
        },
        {
            "USERNAME": "User2",
            "USER_PASSWORD": "test2"
        },
        {
            "USERNAME": "User3",
            "USER_PASSWORD": "test3"
        }
    ]
```

From `obj1` I want the POST value to be appended to the appropriate user in `obj2`.

Final result should look like the below array.

```
[
    {
        "USERNAME": "User1",
        "USER_PASSWORD": "test1",
        "POST": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "USERNAME": "User2",
        "USER_PASSWORD": "test2",
        "POST": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "USERNAME": "User3",
        "USER_PASSWORD": "test3",
        "POST": "Tester"
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post that code and we can try and help you. If you've not tried anything, please go and try something and then come back if you run into any problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj1 = [
                {"POST":"Developer","USERNAME":["User1","User2"]},
                {"POST":"Tester","USERNAME":["User3"]}
            ];
            var obj2 = [
                {"USERNAME":"User1","USER_PASSWORD":"test1"},
                {"USERNAME":"User2","USER_PASSWORD":"test2"},
                {"USERNAME":"User3","USER_PASSWORD":"test3"}];
            var obj3=[];

            obj1.forEach(function(eachObj1) {
                obj2.forEach(function(eachObj2) {
                    if(eachObj1.USERNAME.indexOf(eachObj2.USERNAME) >= 0) {
                        console.log("in if")
                        eachObj2.POST = eachObj1.POST;
                        obj3.push(eachObj2);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
var obj1 = [{"POST":"Developer","USERNAME":["User1","User2"]},{"POST":"Tester","USERNAME":["User3"]}];
var obj2 = [{"USERNAME":"User1","USER_PASSWORD":"test1"},{"USERNAME":"User2","USER_PASSWORD":"test2"},{"USERNAME":"User3","USER_PASSWORD":"test3"}];
$.each(obj2,function(i,val){
   $.each(obj1,function(index,innerVal){

        var post=innerVal.POST;
        $.each(innerVal.USERNAME,function(i,user){
            if(user==val.USERNAME){
                val.POST=post;
            }
        });
    });
});
alert(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z4xZ9/)

Comment: Since the post is tagged with Node.js it's unlikely that they have jQuery included. And including jQuery just to loop through arrays wouldn't be reasonable.